# How do I keep child div from being bound by Knockout JS using foreach and SignalR

Tags: knockout.js, signalr

I have created a FaceBook style commenting system using the following blog post: http://techbrij.com/realtime-post-comment-notifications-signalr-knockout

I extended the functionality by adding a way to toggle the commentSection div by adding/removing the hidden css class name. It works beautifully if I have only one instance of the browser open. However, when I open a second browser, the loading of that browser resets both browser instances comment sections to their default "hidden" class. Would anyone have a suggestion on how to unbind the commentSection div from knockout bindings so that that div is controlled client side and not through knockout? Here is my abbreviated code based on the blog post noted above:

```
HTML:
...
<ul id="msgHolder" class="post-ul" data-bind="foreach: posts">
     <li class="postHolder post-li"> 
        <div class="postFooter">
           ...
           <a class="toggleCommentSection" href="#" data-bind="click: toggleCommentSection, visible: PostComments().length > 0">View Comment(s)</a>
           <div class="commentSection hidden">
              <ul class="post-ul" data-bind="foreach: PostComments">
                ...
              </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
     </li>
</ul>
...

SCRIPT:
function Post(data, hub, owner) {
   ...
   self.toggleCommentSection = function (item, event) {
        if ($(event.target).next('.commentSection').is(':visible')) {
            $(event.target).next('.commentSection').addClass("hidden");
            $(event.target).html("View Comment(s)");
        }
        else {
            $(event.target).next('.commentSection').removeClass("hidden");
            $(event.target).html("Hide Comment(s)");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your server code look like? For it to reset the other browser instance it must be triggering some event from the hub. The site you linked to shows that it is calling Clients.All.loadPosts(ret); do you hide the comment sections there?

Comment: If I hide the comment section there, it hides it for all browser instances. So if I am looking at the comments and another user opens to the same site, it collapses the comments I was looking at. I do call Clients.All.loadPosts(ret) in that particular function

Comment: To clarify my response, I do not have any code to hide the comment section in the loadPosts function. It just adds the returned posts to my current posts: var mappedPosts = $.map(data, function (item) { return new Post(item, self.hub, self); });
        self.posts(mappedPosts);

Comment: So you got me thinking: what if I used Clients.Caller.loadPosts(ret); rather than all. And that did it. I am not sure what other implications this may have, so I will walk through a round of testing and let you know if I find any issues with it. If you would like to set that as an answer rather than a comment, I will be happy to mark it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not that it's still bound to knockoutjs. The problem is that if someone connects, all the posts are loaded again.

From the PostHub:

```
// GET api/WallPost
public void GetPosts()
{
    ...
    Clients.All.loadPosts(ret);
}
```

I think this should be `Clients.Caller.loadPosts(ret)`. But aside from that, this means that if anyone calls `GetPosts()`, the function `loadPosts(data)` is invoked on all clients:

```
self.hub.client.loadPosts = function (data) {
    var mappedPosts = $.map(data, function (item) { return new Post(item, self.hub); });
    self.posts(mappedPosts);
}
```

This will replace the posts, with the new posts. This in turn will render the `<ul id="msgHolder" class="post-ul" data-bind="foreach: posts" />` again, meaning you lost your hidden-state.

To prevent this from happening, you should also be using knockoutjs for remembering the hidden-state:

**Add a property to your client side Post:**

```
self.commentsHidden = ko.observable(true);
```

**The HTML:**

```
<ul id="msgHolder" class="post-ul" data-bind="foreach: posts">
     <li class="postHolder post-li"> 
        <div class="postFooter">
           ...
           <a class="toggleCommentSection" href="#" data-bind="
               click: toggleCommentSection, 
               visible: PostComments().length > 0, 
               text: commentsHidden() ? 'View Comment(s)' : 'Hide Comment(s)'
               "></a>
           <div class="commentSection" data-bind="css: { hidden: commentsHidden }">
              <ul class="post-ul" data-bind="foreach: PostComments">
                ...
              </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
     </li>
</ul>
```

**toggleCommentSection:**

```
self.toggleCommentSection = function() {
    self.commentsHidden(!self.commentsHidden());
}
```

Welcome to the world of Knockout!

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation. Changing the server-side code from Clients.All to Clients.Caller seemed to be enough to fix losing my hidden state. Am I missing something?  Thanks also to the kind "Knockout welcome". It's been an interesting and exciting adventure!  Nothing like learning the hard way.  :)

Comment: This fixes it in your case, but in the future, if you decide to get all the posts again (call `self.hub.server.getPosts()`), you'll lose the hidden state again. But you could then still try and implement commentsHidden via knockout.